# Merging Entries - Craft 2 worked but not Craft 3

Tags: merge

I have this code which merged entries when in Craft 2

```
{% set entriesOne = craft.entries.section('publications').search('nonMembers:0').ids() %}
{% set entriesTwo = craft.entries.section('improveYourClub').search('membersExclusive:1').ids() %}

{% set entriesIds = entriesOne|merge(entriesTwo) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entriesIds) %}
```

However when I updated the site to Craft 3 I'm no longer seeing entries merged. I only get results for the `entriesOne`. not a list of combined entries as expected.

Comment: Weird... if you `{{ dump(entriesOne) }}` and `{{ dump(entriesTwo) }}`, do you get the Ids you're expecting?